# JDBC - Convert SQL string to satisfy Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

It seems like this question has been beaten to death, but I cant find a solution for my situation. In Oracle SQL Developer, I wrote the following query and I know it is syntactically correct (or it at least retrieves the data I need it to).

```
select QUERY.SETID, COUNT(QUERY.GENEID) 
from QUERY, G2
where QUERY.GENEID = G2.GENEID group by QUERY.SETID
order BY COUNT(QUERY.GENEID) DESC;
```

I translated it to my Java program as seen here.

```
String query = "select QUERY.SETID, COUNT QUERY.GENEID"
                        + "from QUERY, G2"
                        + "where QUERY.GENEID = G2.GENEID group by QUERY.SETID "
                        + "order BY COUNT QUERY.GENEID DESC;";
```

Now from many questions I've read, the "order BY" command tends to generate problems so I tried removing that entire fourth line  to read like this.

```
String query = "select QUERY.SETID, COUNT QUERY.GENEID"
                        + "from QUERY, G2"
                        + "where QUERY.GENEID = G2.GENEID group by QUERY.SETID;";
```

But I still receive a FROM keyword not found where expected error. I'd appreciate any help or pointing towards other questions that may help. Thanks.

EDIT: This is the error code I'm receiving

```
Oct 30, 2014 4:36:02 PM Main main
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:853)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1469)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:389)
at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Comment: There are no spaces between your lines! When strings are concatenated everything goes wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is due to missing whitespace between the SQL keywords. Also the `ORDER BY` clause and the unwanted semicolon.

```
String query = "select QUERY.SETID, COUNT(QUERY.GENEID) as CT "
                    + "from QUERY, G2 "
                    + "where QUERY.GENEID = G2.GENEID group by QUERY.SETID "
                    + "order BY CT DESC";
```

Comment: I changed my sql statement verbatim to yours and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried it with and without the COUNT part and still receive the same error. I'd prefer to have it in there but can work without it

Comment: Corrected the ORDER BY clause and the unwanted semicolon.